# Make using implicit rule instead of explicit?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Here is my entire Makefile:

```
TGT = call
OBJS = main.o

.PHONY : clean

$(TGT) : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o : %.s
        $(AS) -o $@ $<

%.s : %.c
        $(CC) -S -o $@ $<

clean :
        $(RM) $(TGT) *.o *.s
```

When I run make, I was expecting:

- main.s gets built from main.c
- main.o gets built from main.s
- call gets built from main.o

Instead what make is doing is:

```
$ make
cc    -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o call main.o
```

Any ideas why it is using the implicit rule for *.o files rather than the explicit one I specified? Note that if I manually create the *.s file first, it uses my explicit rule:

```
$ make main.s
cc -S -o main.s main.c
$ make
as -o main.o main.s
cc -o call main.o
```

Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding something with Make? Shouldn't it recognize that main.s is a prerequisite for main.o, and build main.s using the rule I specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable all built-in suffix rules just by setting empty value for suffix targets:

```
.SUFFIXES:
```

And then set own suffixes:

```
.SUFFIXES: .o .s
```

Running make with flags *-r* or *--no-builtin-rules* should do the same. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html).

Comment: Thank you. Another option I found was to [cancel built-in rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) using an empty rule with the same pattern but no recipe.

Comment: @xchrishawk yes, this is also an option